# How to implement less compiler when saving options

Tags: plugin, css

This question is not so specific, but I will ask it anyway.

Is it possible (better possible and easy) to use less compiler when saving options for a component or plugin?

What I want - many content plugins offer user input css, which they inject directly into html code as inline style.
My idea is to modify and compile css file when pressing 'Save' button in the backend. This will eliminate use of inline css-es, but will preserve option for user modifications there.
I've read about firing less compiler at page load, but I think this should be avoided too.

What is your opinion? And to be more specific - what kind of code I need and where to locate Save action?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to when **any** component, plugin or module is saved, then this I do not believe is possible. If I'm not mistaken, you can only manipulate the save function for each individual component.

What I would recommend doing is creating a plugin and compile the LESS using the `onBeforeCompileHead` event. You're going to have to copy the `compileLess` function and make some changes to it as it. For this, check line **742** of the following file:

```
administrator\components\com_templates\models\template.php
```

You plugin could look a little like this:

```
class plgSystemCompileLess extends JPlugin
{

    public function onBeforeCompileHead()
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        // Only compile this for the frontend
        if ($app->isSite()) 
        {
            // Call your compileLess function here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to modify one plugin. There is a lot of user css inputs, and all that is going inline. I will try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

For automatic and controlled rendering of less in joomla try out 
the jprooless library if you are an developer/template-designer. You can configure it, also you are able to force the rendering on each page-load(for development/testing is usfull).

Template Administrators with lesser knowledge about php coding and joomla internals use the pkg_jproofless*. is written in top of the library

http://wiki.jproof.de/projects/joomla-library-jproof-less/wiki

hope that helps